# Monitor detection issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have my monitor connected via DVI (it's an old AOC) and also connected via HDMI to a HDMI 5 way switch which is output to a TV. When the TV and the switch are off the PC randomly makes the 'device detected' sound and reframes the monitor as though I have just plugged in another monitor, it kind of shrinks the screen a bit then goes back, if that makes sense.

How to figure out whats causing it?

Comment: Are all your devices grounded properly?

Comment: I presume so - don't know how I would check?

Comment: Do you know how to use a multi-meter? If not, then grab an outlet tester for about $20 from your local hardware store and stick them in every outlet to test them. Looks like this (https://www.amazon.com/electrical-outlet-tester/s?k=electrical+outlet+tester0).  You'll need the 3 prong ones that actually plugs into the outlet.